# Deactivate a TP-LINK modem-router-access point through telnet

Tags: command-line, router, wireless-access-point, modem

I have a TP-LINK Modem-Router (TD-W8951ND) that I want to deactivate it's access point (wireless) through telnet but I can't find proper command.

All the main commands are:

> TP-LINK> ?
>
> Valid commands are:
>
> sys
> exit
> ether
> wan
> etherdbg
> tcephydbg
> ip
> bridge
> dot1q
> pktqos
> show
> set
>
> lan

How can I do that with these commands?

Comment: Based on the list of commands it does not appear you can disable the wireless access point functionality from a ssh connection.  What makes you think this should be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For enabling : `tp-link>rtwlan enableap`

For disabling : `tp-link>rtwlan disableap`

Answer (score 0):

First connect to modem by telnet then enter username and password.
After successfully authenticate you can get list of all supported command by pressing question mark (?) in command line.
For example in D-Link modem you can disable/enable WLAN by following in CMD:

```
C:\>telnet 192.168.1.1
username: YourUsername
Password: YourPassword
```

after successfully authenticate, type following command:
1- For enable WLAN:

```
TBS>>wlan enable
```

2- For disable WLAN:

```
TBS>>wlan disable
```

and in TP-Link modems you can use this commands (Tested on TD-W8960N):
1- For enable WLAN:

```
>wlctl up
```

2- For disable WLAN:

```
>wlctl down
```

Comment: How does this differ from what the question already says?

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't find such a command for TP-LINK.

Comment: I add TP-Link command too. Please check it

Comment: @YousefRahimyAkhondzadeh Believe me or not that commands aren't valid on my "TD-W8951N" :(

Comment: Link after link after link on how to disable the CLI using the CLI. I need to _use_ the CLI, but I cannot telnet in to "wlan enable" telnet.

Answer (score 0):

This may help one attempting to understand the TP-LINK command-line interface, for which documentation would appear to be nonexistent.

The Zyxel CLI would appear to be the same or very similar. You could use a user guide like [this](ftp://ftp2.zyxel.com/P-660W-T1_v2/cli_reference_guide/P-660W-T1%20v2_1.pdf) (note: this is a direct PDF download link), to learn about the CLI.